# Learning and Mastering CSS3

Tags: css

I know the basics of CSS and can do a fair amount of styling with CSS, right now I am advised to learn CSS3.

My question is **how can I master CSS3?**

Please suggest any sites so that I can learn CSS3 from scratch and provide sample exercises that I can work on.

Thanks.

Comment: @Leo I tried but can't find some documentation kind of sites, like the ones for AngulerJS and jQuery.

Comment: I dont think you're trying hard enough...CSS3 and HTML5 are a hot topic anywhere in the globe and you will find 1000s of websites in any language

Comment: @Leo I was able to find sites like the one I got in the answers for this question but I was not able to find a simple enough documentation kind of content where I can understand CSS3 in and out. Like this one which I found for AngularJs http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/how-to-learn-angular.html

Comment: I don't get how you understand AngularJS and jQuery but don't understand CSS :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

[lynda.com](http://lynda.com)

or [tutplus.com.](http://tutplus.com)

there are many websites.

http://courses.tutsplus.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&view=&search[keywords]=css3&button=

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/45-useful-css3-tutorials-and-techniques/

http://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/web-design